Getting an ImportError while trying to import from __init__.py
NOTE:
Sorry if i dont format this correctly or something, Im newer to asking questions on stack overflow
Some of my code:
"""Server tools script"""

from typing import Dict
from types import FunctionType
from . import REDIS


# The rest of it

This error is what i am getting from the code:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\ever\Documents\overgames\app.py", line 11, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\ever\Documents\overgames\app.py", line 7, in main
    import servertools as dev
  File "C:\Users\ever\Documents\overgames\servertools.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import REDIS
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I Tried from overgames import REDIS but didnt work

Could it be that the line should read from REDIS import . ?

Hi, does this answer help?

Moreover, what is REDIS? Do you have a REDIS.py file in your directory?

@LuxGiammi I have REDIS in init.py, Really just a basic redis server                                                 EDIT: Turns out this uses md formatting so the init.py turns out bold

@Zico No, REDIS is a constant within init.py       EDIT: Maybe but probably not

import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from overgames import REDIS

by including the parent directory in sys.path, you can use an absolute import for REDIS

Im gonna try that

Is there any way to stop pylint and pylance from yelling at me, Otherwise ill go with this alone
